# Insert to DB if not exist

Tags: java, sqlite, android-studio

I tried to insert row to DB if it doesn't exist by email:

```
public boolean AddUserIfNotExist(String email, String password, String username) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = m_helper.getWritableDatabase();


    //String Query = "INSERT OR IGNORE INTO USERS(email, password, username) 
    //values('" + email + "','" + password + "','" + username + "');";

    String Query = "INSERT INTO USERS(email, password, username) " +
            "SELECT '" + email + "','" + password + "','" + username + "' " 
            + "WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM USERS WHERE email = '" + email + "');";

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);

    if(cursor.getCount() <= 0) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Why it doesn't work? cursor.getCount always returns false.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An INSERT statement does not return any rows, so you cannot use `rawQuery`; for INSERT, you must use `execSQL` instead.

If you want to determine whether the record existed or not, just do it separately (also, use parameters to avoid string formatting problems):

```
if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, "Users",
                                  "email = ?", new String[] { email })) > 0) {
    // probably UPDATE?
    return true;
} else {
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Users(email, password, username) VALUES(?,?,?)",
               new Object[] { email, password, username });
    return false;
}
```

Comment: queryNumEntries is not like select query? If the answer is yes, is it uneffective to make two requests to the DB?
I tried to write it in one query in order to make it with one request.

Comment: Why do you think that two request are inefficient? There is no client/server communication overhead. Did you measure it?